# Convenient codesigning in VS Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, sign

like so many others, I try to migrate from ISE with ISESteroids to VSCODE.
I managed, to create a task for my codesigning. Via macros, I was able to make a Keybinding to save the current file and sign it with a key combination.
However, I miss my ISESteroids that did this automatically.
Our Executionpolicy is Allsigned, so I can not debug without signing the file first.
Is there any convenient way to automatically save and sign the file, when I start debugging?

Comment: Not without writing your own task to do this. ISESteroids is a great addon, but no such thing exists in VSCode or starting your VSCode session with your user or process ExecutionPolicy set as you need it. EP are set computer, user process. EP's are nto security boundaries and easily bypassed. Yet, little reason to since you do conrol you user, process EP settings, even if you computer setting is controlled by GPO.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Reply.
Unfortunately, in our Setup the possibility to bypass the execution Policy is diasbled. I allready tried that and a lot of other things.
Is there a way, to automatically trigger the task e.g. when i strat the debugger or when the file is saved? That would help a lot in terms of Convenience.

Comment: The Plugin "Save and Run Ext" did the trick for me.
With the Plugin, I could start my codesigning script everytime I save a .ps1 file.
Since the debugger also saves the file first, I now got my automatted codesigning.